# How do i change test type from manual_one to automated in allure testops?

Tags: allure

I have 2 workflows:
[image: example:]

My tests have status "automated"
[image: automated status]

But when i open filters and filter by "automated", they all marked as manual once.
[image: all are manual]

How do i change their type to automated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your tests will be marked as automated only if they are uploaded from test-results via ide or CI\CD. IF you have test runs associated with a test, then this test will be automated.